# Display content that reference the logged in user using Views

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have a content type Job with a [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) field. This field (field_data_field_job_applicants) has a target type of User, and maximum number of values set to 10.

What I have got working so far is adding the users (specifically their uid) to this list when they click "Apply Job" on a job page.

What I am trying to do now is: when a job applicant logs in, they will see a collection of jobs they applied for.

More specifically, I want to tell the Views block to only display jobs where [current-user:uid] is referenced by field_data_field_job_applicants.

Comment: You want to display all the jobs the logedin user has?

Comment: @NoSssweat yes. Please look at my edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a content view and add a contextual filter for the field you created. My test contextual filter was called `Content: User Ref Test`. Your contextual filter will have the same name as the field you created.

2 . In the contextual filter's settings, click `Provide Default: User ID from logged in User`. This will only show content where the user has been referenced.